# Google Action | Agent context is giving '-' in agent.context.get()

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

My submitted action as it is not responding properly. I found that dialog flow action is giving `'-'` for `agent.context.get('<name>')` due to which I am getting `'undefined'` as final result. I have never been able to replicate this issue at my end on real device after several long retries.

Code snippet:

```
//agent set context
const context = {
'name': 'riddle-index',
'lifespan': 10,
'parameters': {
'rindex': index
}
};

agent.context.set(context);

//agent get context
let riddleIndex = agent.context.get('riddle-
index');
```

My **package.json** contains

```
"dependencies": {
"actions-on-google": "^2.6.0",
"dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1",
"firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.0.0"
},
```

**//Logs agent context:**

**When context is having `'-'`:**

agent context {"contexts":{"-":{"name":"-","parameters":{"no-input":0,"no-match":0,"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}}},"session":"projects/musical-instruments-quiz-8a073/agent/environments/__aog-4/users/-/sessions/ABwppHFMeT9XwzM6qV8uaK1EiCdMMKX6WiL6CcAgXKiqAjRg-X1au6qNz7QnHaJLSUFU_jRv4RCi5Awe2AGklCccN9nlkH8KG_4lv4fS","inputContexts":{"-":{"name":"-","parameters":{"no-input":0,"no-match":0,"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}}}}

**When context is having slot values:**

agent context {"contexts":{"riddle-index":{"name":"riddle-index","lifespan":10,"parameters":{"rindex":13,"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},"actions_capability_audio_output":{"name":"actions_capability_audio_output","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},"actions_capability_media_response_audio":{"name":"actions_capability_media_response_audio","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},"actions_capability_account_linking":{"name":"actions_capability_account_linking","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},"google_assistant_input_type_voice":{"name":"google_assistant_input_type_voice","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},"**system_counters**":{"name":"**system_counters**","parameters":{"no-input":0,"no-match":0,"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}}},"session":"projects/musical-instruments-quiz-8a073/agent/sessions/ABwppHGaPKiEmY8CePzJNdQXwQqMfKAmP0QUNIDyNfyGmuS5ScgqXa4pJKYq4B7Z52uZBXFZEIjg5YmzOWQroYudMNryOrkAmL--sEFz","inputContexts":{"riddle-index":{"name":"riddle-index","lifespan":10,"parameters":{"rindex":13,"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},"actions_capability_audio_output":{"name":"actions_capability_audio_output","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},"actions_capability_media_response_audio":{"name":"actions_capability_media_response_audio","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},"actions_capability_account_linking":{"name":"actions_capability_account_linking","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},"google_assistant_input_type_voice":{"name":"google_assistant_input_type_voice","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},"**system_counters**":{"name":"**system_counters**","parameters":{"no-input":0,"no-match":0,"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}}}}

**//Logs Request body:**

Dialogflow Request body: {"responseId":"f9b56859-cb12-431a-a46c-02c92c5a64be-426bc00a","queryResult":{"queryText":"violin","parameters":{"any":"Violin"},"allRequiredParamsPresent":true,"outputContexts":[{"name":"projects/musical-instruments-quiz-8a073/agent/environments/**aog-4/users/-/sessions/ABwppHFMeT9XwzM6qV8uaK1EiCdMMKX6WiL6CcAgXKiqAjRg-X1au6qNz7QnHaJLSUFU_jRv4RCi5Awe2AGklCccN9nlkH8KG_4lv4fS/contexts/riddle-index","lifespanCount":10,"parameters":{"rindex":6,"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},{"name":"projects/musical-instruments-quiz-8a073/agent/environments/__aog-4/users/-/sessions/ABwppHFMeT9XwzM6qV8uaK1EiCdMMKX6WiL6CcAgXKiqAjRg-X1au6qNz7QnHaJLSUFU_jRv4RCi5Awe2AGklCccN9nlkH8KG_4lv4fS/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},{"name":"projects/musical-instruments-quiz-8a073/agent/environments/__aog-4/users/-/sessions/ABwppHFMeT9XwzM6qV8uaK1EiCdMMKX6WiL6CcAgXKiqAjRg-X1au6qNz7QnHaJLSUFU_jRv4RCi5Awe2AGklCccN9nlkH8KG_4lv4fS/contexts/actions_capability_media_response_audio","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},{"name":"projects/musical-instruments-quiz-8a073/agent/environments/__aog-4/users/-/sessions/ABwppHFMeT9XwzM6qV8uaK1EiCdMMKX6WiL6CcAgXKiqAjRg-X1au6qNz7QnHaJLSUFU_jRv4RCi5Awe2AGklCccN9nlkH8KG_4lv4fS/contexts/actions_capability_account_linking","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},{"name":"projects/musical-instruments-quiz-8a073/agent/environments/__aog-4/users/-/sessions/ABwppHFMeT9XwzM6qV8uaK1EiCdMMKX6WiL6CcAgXKiqAjRg-X1au6qNz7QnHaJLSUFU_jRv4RCi5Awe2AGklCccN9nlkH8KG_4lv4fS/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},{"name":"projects/musical-instruments-quiz-8a073/agent/environments/__aog-4/users/-/sessions/ABwppHFMeT9XwzM6qV8uaK1EiCdMMKX6WiL6CcAgXKiqAjRg-X1au6qNz7QnHaJLSUFU_jRv4RCi5Awe2AGklCccN9nlkH8KG_4lv4fS/contexts/actions_capability_web_browser","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},{"name":"projects/musical-instruments-quiz-8a073/agent/environments/__aog-4/users/-/sessions/ABwppHFMeT9XwzM6qV8uaK1EiCdMMKX6WiL6CcAgXKiqAjRg-X1au6qNz7QnHaJLSUFU_jRv4RCi5Awe2AGklCccN9nlkH8KG_4lv4fS/contexts/google_assistant_input_type_voice","parameters":{"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}},{"name":"projects/musical-instruments-quiz-8a073/agent/environments/__aog-4/users/-/sessions/ABwppHFMeT9XwzM6qV8uaK1EiCdMMKX6WiL6CcAgXKiqAjRg-X1au6qNz7QnHaJLSUFU_jRv4RCi5Awe2AGklCccN9nlkH8KG_4lv4fS/contexts/__system_counters**","parameters":{"no-input":0,"no-match":0,"any":"Violin","any.original":"violin"}}],"intent":{"name":"projects/musical-instruments-quiz-8a073/agent/intents/e74ab319-eb4e-45d5-b3cd-40b1a567fa68","displayName":"RiddleAnswer Intent"},"intentDetectionConfidence":1,"languageCode":"en"},"originalDetectIntentRequest":{"source":"google","version":"2","payload":{"user":{"locale":"en-US","userVerificationStatus":"VERIFIED"},"conversation":{"conversationId":"ABwppHFMeT9XwzM6qV8uaK1EiCdMMKX6WiL6CcAgXKiqAjRg-X1au6qNz7QnHaJLSUFU_jRv4RCi5Awe2AGklCccN9nlkH8KG_4lv4fS","type":"ACTIVE","conversationToken":"[\"riddle-index\"]"},"inputs":[{"intent":"actions.intent.TEXT","rawInputs":[{"inputType":"VOICE","query":"violin"}],"arguments":[{"name":"text","rawText":"violin","textValue":"violin"}]}],"surface":{"capabilities":[{"name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"},{"name":"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"},{"name":"actions.capability.ACCOUNT_LINKING"},{"name":"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"},{"name":"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"}]},"isInSandbox":true,"availableSurfaces":[{"capabilities":[{"name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"},{"name":"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"},{"name":"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"}]}]}},"session":"projects/musical-instruments-quiz-8a073/agent/environments/__aog-4/users/-/sessions/ABwppHFMeT9XwzM6qV8uaK1EiCdMMKX6WiL6CcAgXKiqAjRg-X1au6qNz7QnHaJLSUFU_jRv4RCi5Awe2AGklCccN9nlkH8KG_4lv4fS"}

Comment: where is the code snippet? You could also better format the jsons, it will help other users to find an answer for you

Comment: I tried to improve the typesetting, but as @Alberto says, please be a bit kinder to your audience by being more concise.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the agent.context.set() method incorrectly. This new method takes different parameters.

In the past, agent.setContext() takes an object. It seems like you're using agent.context.set like the setContext() method.

The correct signature of agent.context.set() is passing in the following parameters in order: contextName, lifespan, context parameter object);

For example,

```
agent.context.set('context_name_1', 10, {'param1' : 'abc'});
agent.context.set('context_name_2', 11, {'param2' : 2});
```